# camera always change position when enter VR mode in smartphone

Tags: aframe, webvr

I need to position my camera to back a bit bcs of things. but everytime i enter the VR mode in smartphone, the camera always goes forward. how to fix this?

This is the camera code i use

```
<a-entity camera look-controls wasd-controls position="0 1 2">
    <a-cursor
              fuse="false"
              geometry="primitive: ring; radiusInner: 0.01; radiusOuter: 0.016"
              material="color: #efdf02"
              position="0 0 -1"></a-cursor>
  </a-entity>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create and position an entity that wraps the camera (aka [camera rig](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/docs/components/camera.md)):

```
<a-entity position=“0 1 2”>
  <a-entity camera look-controls></a-entity>
</a-entity>
```